# Python: Fastest way to compute multivariate regression p-values

Tags: python, linear-regression, p-value

My project involves computing millions of linear regressions for which I need to save both the coefficients and the p-values. The coefficients can be quickly obtained using from the skipy package; `lstsq(X_train, y_train, lapack_driver='gelsy', check_finite = False)`. However, I am still looking for a way to quickly compute the corresponding p-values and I was hoping maybe someone here has an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.stats.linregress`. Read the docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html).

Here is an example:

```py
# Fake data
x = rng.random(10)
y = 1.6*x + rng.random(10)

# Compute coefficients and p-value
slope, intercept, r, p, se = linregress(x, y)
```